# How to fix "has no address records" in BIND9

Tags: server, bind9

I have a problem while setting up a local DNS-Server for pentesting.

When i want to start the BIND9 Server, i get the error:

"zone victim.local/IN: NS 'server1.victim.local' has no address records (A or AAAA)

"zone victim.local/IN: NS 'server2.victim.local' has no address records (A or AAAA)

*db.victim.local file:*

```
;
; BIND data file for Zone victim.local
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. (
                              2         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@               IN      NS      server1.victim.local.
@               IN      NS      server2.victim.local.
parrot          IN      A       192.168.178.78  ; Parrot OS
metasploitable  IN      A       192.168.178.79  ; Metasploitable
www             IN      CNAME   server1.victim.local.  ; Alias für Webserver
ftp             IN      CNAME   server1.victim.local.  ; Alias für FTP-Server
```

*db.192.168.178.0 file:*

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for Reverse Zone 192.168.178.0/24
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. (
                              1         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      server2.victim.local.
212     IN      PTR     server1.victim.local.
213     IN      PTR     server2.victim.local.
207     IN      PTR     win7.victim.local.
210     IN      PTR     win10.victim.local.
205     IN      PTR     parrot.victim.local.
206     IN      PTR     metasploitable.victim.local.
```

Comment: This is not a programming question, but rather system administration, and should be taken to another site.  But the answer seems self-explanatory: you should add A records for server1 and server2, since you currently don't have any.

Comment: I did not know i will post in on another forum. Anyway how do i add them?

Comment: >Anyway how do i add them?
^^ like the other two A reccords?! as these servers are inside your zone.
    server1   IN  A       1.2.3.4
    server2   IN  AAAA       5600::78